# YUI3 Selectors / query

Tags: javascript, html, selector, yui

There is a list of check boxes in a table and i have assigned a unique key to value attribute of each checkbox. What should be the selector in YUI3 so that i can get a single checkbox object if I know its value.

Following is the sample of the structure:

```
<table id="mytable">
<tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" value="1" /></td><td>Apple store</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" value="2" /></td><td>Play store</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Code required in the following format:
Y.one("#mytable input[type=checkbox,value=1]");

This must return the checkbox object for Apple Store but its not working.. any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an attribute selector for each attribute you are trying to match. You can't combine the name/value pairs in a single attribute selector.

```
[type=checkbox][value=1]
```

Comment: wow, that worked fine. Following is the code i used: Y.one("#mytable input[type=\"checkbox\"][value=\"1\"]")

Comment: How can I get the object of second TD which contains the label for this checkbox using YUI3 selectors? Assuming that I only knew the value attribute of checkbox.

Comment: I figured it out. Y.one("#mytable input[type=\"checkbox\"][value=\"1\"]").get("parentNode").get("nextSibling")